# Rosalind: Open Reading Frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, bioinformatics, rosalind

I am working through the 'Rosalind' problems and I've become stuck on what the issue with my code is... The problem is:

> Either strand of a DNA double helix can serve as the coding strand for
>   RNA transcription. Hence, a given DNA string implies six total reading
>   frames, or ways in which the same region of DNA can be translated into
>   amino acids: three reading frames result from reading the string
>   itself, whereas three more result from reading its reverse complement.
>
> An open reading frame (ORF) is one which starts from the start codon
>   and ends by stop codon, without any other stop codons in between.
>   Thus, a candidate protein string is derived by translating an open
>   reading frame into amino acids until a stop codon is reached.
>
> Given: A DNA string s of length at most 1 kbp in FASTA format.
>
> Return: Every distinct candidate protein string that can be translated
>   from ORFs of s. Strings can be returned in any order.

Here is my code (Python):

```
    DNA_Codons = {
        'TTT': 'F',     'CTT': 'L',     'ATT': 'I',     'GTT': 'V',
        'TTC': 'F',     'CTC': 'L',     'ATC': 'I',     'GTC': 'V',
        'TTA': 'L',     'CTA': 'L',     'ATA': 'I',     'GTA': 'V',
        'TTG': 'L',     'CTG': 'L',     'ATG': 'M',     'GTG': 'V',
        'TCT': 'S',     'CCT': 'P',     'ACT': 'T',     'GCT': 'A',
        'TCC': 'S',     'CCC': 'P',     'ACC': 'T',     'GCC': 'A',
        'TCA': 'S',     'CCA': 'P',     'ACA': 'T',     'GCA': 'A',
        'TCG': 'S',     'CCG': 'P',     'ACG': 'T',     'GCG': 'A',
        'TAT': 'Y',     'CAT': 'H',     'AAT': 'N',     'GAT': 'D',
        'TAC': 'Y',     'CAC': 'H',     'AAC': 'N',     'GAC': 'D',
        'TAA': '-',     'CAA': 'Q',     'AAA': 'K',     'GAA': 'E',
        'TAG': '-',     'CAG': 'Q',     'AAG': 'K',     'GAG': 'E',
        'TGT': 'C',     'CGT': 'R',     'AGT': 'S',     'GGT': 'G',
        'TGC': 'C',     'CGC': 'R',     'AGC': 'S',     'GGC': 'G',
        'TGA': '-',     'CGA': 'R',     'AGA': 'R',     'GGA': 'G',
        'TGG': 'W',     'CGG': 'R',     'AGG': 'R',     'GGG': 'G'
    }
    bases={"A":"T",
           "T":"A",
           "G":"C",
           "C":"G"}

    def Pro(DNA, start, Rev):
            #Calculates the Reverse compliment if using
            if Rev == True:
                    reverse=DNA[::-1]
                    compliment=[]
                    for base in reverse:
                            compliment+=bases[base]
                    Seq="".join(compliment)
            elif Rev== False:
                    Seq=DNA
            Protein=[]
            #Finds a start codon
            for i in range(start, len(Seq),3):
                    codon=Seq[i:i+3]
                    if codon=="ATG":
                            #Starting from that start codon, returns a protein, breaks if stop codon
                            #-2 included so that it's always in blocks of 3
                            for j in range(i,len(Seq)-2,3):
                                    new_codon=Seq[j:j+3]
                                    if DNA_Codons[new_codon]!="-":
                                            Protein+=[DNA_Codons[new_codon]]
                                    else:
                                            #Adds in the '-' to split proteins that start within the same Reading Frame
                                            Protein+=[DNA_Codons[new_codon]]
                                            break
            return Protein
    f = open('rosalind_orf.txt','r').read()
    #Puts each FASTA String into an arrary
    strings=f.split(">")

    #removes the FASTA ID from the string in array and new line characters
    for i in range(len(strings)):
            strings[i]=strings[i].strip("Rosalind_0123456789")
            strings[i]=strings[i].replace("\n","")

    DNA=strings[1]
    #Adds proteins from all Open Reading Frames
    Proteins=[]
    for i in range(len(DNA)):
            Proteins+="".join(Pro(DNA,i,False)).split('-')
            Proteins+="".join(Pro(DNA,i,True)).split('-')
    #Mades a list of Unique Proteins and prints them
    Unique_Proteins=[]
    for p in Proteins:
            if (p not in Unique_Proteins and p!=""):
                    Unique_Proteins+=[p]
                    print p
```

Using the sample data:

> > Rosalind_99 AGCCATGTAGCTAACTCAGGTTACATGGGGATGACCCCGCGACTTGGATTAGAGTCTCTTTTGGAATAAGCCTGAATGATCCGAGTAGCATCTCAG

My code works fine, however for every question dataset I've been given it fails...

Here is one of the question datasets that I've failed on:

> > Rosalind_1485 GACCAGAATGCGTTAGTCGGCCTCAGAGCGCACAAAAACCAGTATTTACAAAGTGGGACG
> >     TAGCGCCCCGCGGCGTCCTTTTGCCCTATCGAAAGTATAGGCATCAGCTTTTTACCACCT
> >     TGTCATAGGTAAACTGCCCGACCCAGGTCCGGCCCTCAGCCCAACGCAGATAAACCAAGG
> >     TTATAGATGTGGCCTGTAGGCATATTGCTCTTAATGTTATAAAGAGCGAAGCGTGGTCTC
> >     GGTTTGTAAACATTAATCAAATTCCCAGGCACTAAGCCATGGTCGCCCCGGATTGGTTTT
> >     CCGGTGTACGCATCGGTGGCAGCTGGAGGGGACAGTTTAGGTGCTGCAATTGAACATGAA
> >     ACTGCACGAAAGGTGGGGTGGGCCGGATCTTGCGGGCCTCGAAAGGGTAGTGTTCCTCTG
> >     CTATCTAGTCCAATTACCTGTAGTATATATGATCAGGCCGTCGGTTACTTAGCTAAGTAA
> >     CCGACGGCCTGATCATCTCCTAGGAAATGGTCCTGAATGCGAACTAGGTTCCGTGGAATG
> >     ATGGGGCCCAGAGGAAACCTGTACGCAATGGATCCCGGACAGATAGACCGGGAGGTCTTG
> >     CAACCTCTTGTGGGAGTTACAGGCCGTACCTGAATTGCCCTCGTACCATTTGAAATGGTG
> >     CGACGCCTGTACGCAACAATCGTTCGCCTGGATAATACAGACGGCCATTTCTGTAGGAAC
> >     GATACCGTAACGCGACGTCAGGCATGACGTTAACTGCGTCACGTTTCATACCACTATGTG
> >     AGGTACCCACTCCTTCATTTACCGCGAGATAAAGAGCCACCACCACCTTCTCTTGGTTTC
> >     CATGCGCCGATCGGCTAAACGTGCATCACATTCAGGCGAAGAGTCAAATGGAAGCTCGCA
> >     ATTTTAGGCCTTTATGGCGAATATCCCGCAAGCCTTAGGCGCGT

Obviously this code is nowhere near efficient and there's lot that could be improved upon, I'm just curious as to why it's not working.

Comment: 1 - on rosalind_99, your code gives `['ATG', 'ATC', 'CGA', 'GTA', 'GCA', 'TCT', 'CAG']` as a legitimate protein even though there's no stop codon.   Is that correct behavior? (i only know as much about this as scanning google tells me)

Comment: 2 - If your code is failing on Rosalind_1485, how do you know it's failing?  What kind of failure message are you getting?  Was the sample data also in a text file? Perhaps you are reading the text file incorrectly

Comment: I tried your code with Rosalind99 and it produces two additional outputs not mentioned in the Rosalind sample output: MIRVASQ & MA. Do you experience the same?

Comment: @Mr.T The Rosalind sample output is trash. In this particular case my code outputs all the sample data except for the first protein string. And I can't seem to find said string anywhere in the DNA string either.

Comment: @Mr.T I think the problem wanted a string that was terminated by a stop codon.